# Detect if Recent Apps (aka the Overview Screen) is currently being shown

Tags: android, android-service, android-recents, recent-screens

I would like my service to be able to detect when the recent apps screen is being shown. Is there some way for me to notify my service when this happens?

Comment: you can use accessibility service, i don't think there is any other way

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy Interesting... What kind of accessibility events would I need to look for?